При position:relative на текст пропадает текст
Когда оставляю только картинки position relative, видно только часть которая указанная на фото

Когда я ставлю position relative для текста и для ссылки оно почему-то пропадает и их просто становится не видно.
Когда оставляю position аbsolute то их видно, но только часть, а всё остальное почему-то накрывается секции(как на фото)
.view-tours {
  height: 100vh;
}


.mountins {
  position: relative;
  width: 830px;
  height: 475px;
  left: 262px;
  top: 160px;
}


.num {
  position: absolute;
  width: 63px;
  height: 28px;
  left: 312px;
  top: 198px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-family: Playfair Display;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 28px;
  letter-spacing: 0%;
  text-align: left;
}

.moon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 61px;
  height: 28px;
  left: 312px;
  top: 226px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 28px;
  letter-spacing: 0%;
  text-align: left;
}

.image-hawai-left h4 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 201px;
  height: 68px;
  left: 322px;
  top: 522px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 28px;
  letter-spacing: 0%;
  text-align: left;
}

.aroww-2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 0;
  left: 992px;
  top: 566px;
}

.all-directions h3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 445px;
  height: 138px;
  right: 283px;
  top: 202px;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-family: Playfair Display;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 55px;
  letter-spacing: 0%;
  text-align: left;
}

.all-directions p {
  position: relative;
  width: 415px;
  height: 99px;
  right: 313px;
  top: 370px;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 33px;
  letter-spacing: 0%;
  text-align: left;
}

.all-directions a {
  position: relative;
  width: 270px;
  height: 75px;
  right: 458px;
  top: 519px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid rgb(250, 194, 50);
  border-radius: 38px;
  color: rgb(250, 194, 50);
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 0%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 37px;
}


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

Добавьте код html
